# Trying to work out some leaks for iPad game

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a slight problem where when the user plays my game for more than 20 minutes or so it begins to slow quite considerably. However I have been trying to work through the issues pretty hard as of late but still no luck. I have tried the leaks instrument and I now have that squared away, but I read at "bbum's weblog" about using the Allocations Instrument and taking heap shots. But i dont quite understand what i am looking at, could some one give me a hand with this?

My game involves users selecting words. I took a heap shot after each word was selected, but i am not too sure how exactly to read this. Is the heap Growth column what is currently running or is it was has been added to what is currenlly running?

And what is the # Persistent?

Also why is the # Persistent jump so much? Could that be my memory problem?

[image]

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If it's slowing down, why not try CPU profiling instead? Unless you're getting memory warnings, what makes you think it's a leak?

Comment: well being a novice, i have no idea what it is, Ill try that now

Comment: Well taking a look at the time profiler, I realized my answer  to your question. I think that it's a leak because it runs real well right at the start and then slows down over time.

Comment: James, that kind of behaviour doesn't always mean 'leak'. Leaks in iOS don't slow things down - they cause crashes. Slow down could mean that some piece of code you've written doesn't scale well as it operates on larger sets of data. By running the time profiler, you'll see which piece of code is taking up the most time and from that you will get a clue as to what's going wrong. You might, for example, be adding player's guesses to a list and then working through that list. The longer the list, the more time gets taken up. You end up devising a more efficient algorithm as bbum suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heap growth column represents all of the allocations in that iteration that did not exist prior to that iteration but *continue to exist in all subsequent iterations*.

I.e. Heapshot 4 shows a 10.27KB permanent growth in the size of your heap.

If you were to take an additional Heapshot and any of the objects in any of the previous iterations were deallocated for whatever reason, the corresponding iteration's heapshot would decrease in size.

In this case, the heapshot data is not going to be terribly useful.  Sure;  you can dive in an d look at the various objects sticking around, but you don't have a consistent pattern across each iteration.

I [wrote considerably more about this in a weblog post](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

> If it's slowing down, why not try CPU profiling instead? Unless you're
>   getting memory warnings, what makes you think it's a leak?

Tim's comment is correct in that you should be focusing on CPU usage.  However, it is quite effective to assume that an app is slowing down because of increased algorithmic cost associated with a growing working set.  I.e. if there are more objects in memory, and those objects are still in use, then it takes more time to muck with 'em.

That isn't the case here;  your heap isn't growing *that* significantly and, thus, it sounds like you have a pure algorithmic issue if your app is truly slowing down.

Comment: each heapshot that I have taken here are performed after the user completes one action, say they were to make a couple hundred actions might that be significant growth?

Comment: Yeah -- it is of concern, but you are showing less than 50K growth across those runs and much of that is likely due to caching that'll fall out of play over time.  The slowdown is a much bigger concern right now.  BTW: with heapshot analysis, it is most effective to do something, take heapshot, do that same thing, take heapshot, and repeat a few more times...

Answer (score 0):

Does your game save files to NSUserDefaults or to an any arrays. If so as the game is played and more and more stuff is added to the array it would take longer to loop through it hence gradually slowing down the game.